# Ubuntu phone (Aquarius 4.5) change of UMTS frequency

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-touch, aquaris, frequency

I recently moved from Switzerland to Colombia. Apparently the UMTS frequency of my operator (Tigo) here is 1900 MHZ while the phone is on 2100 MHZ.
Therefore I can't get a connection.

Is there a way to change that somehow via terminal or is this hardware related?

Answer (score 0):

It's related to your hardware , you have no chance.